# Has Karma Ever Removed Her Metal Leg?

Tags: marvel, x-men, new-mutants

I was largely curious of this because I know very little of the character after she got her prosthetic leg. I was just curious, has she ever been shown to remove it?

If so, for what purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She takes it off in [Astonishing X-Men #56](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Astonishing_X-Men_Vol_3_56)

[image]

[image]

As to *why*, it's because she's removed it to adjust it, and then can't be bothered to put it back on before having her lunch.